# Why does the numerator and denominator have to be 0 for a value of x in order for there to be a hole?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does 0/0 result in a hole on a graph and not 5/0? Aren't they both undefined?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about functions like $f(x) = \frac{x + 5}{x}$ vs $g(x) = \frac{x}{x}$.

I would say that both of them leave holes in the graph, in the sense that neither $f$ nor $g$ are defined at $0$.

The difference isn't how they behave *at* zero, it's how they behave *near* zero. Pick some small number $\epsilon > 0$. We know that $f(\epsilon)$ is large, and $g(\epsilon) = 1$. As $\epsilon$ gets smaller and smaller, $f(\epsilon)$ gets larger and larger. But $g(x)$ stays steady at $1$.

Note that none of this argument uses what $f$ and $g$ actually are at $0$, just what they are "nearby" zero.